# I cannot get my printf statements to align in java

Tags: java, printf

I am having a spot of trouble with my printf statements. I cannot get them to accurately. This is the code snippet that I am having trouble with.

```
while(choice != 4){
        if(choice == 1){
            System.out.println("NAME            ID          GPA\n");
            for(j = 0; j < i ;j++){
                System.out.printf("%s", fullName[j]);
                System.out.printf("%10d", id[j]);
                System.out.printf("%15.2f\n", gpa[j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

It prints this.

```
NAME            ID          GPA

Hoffman Caleb Joseph         1           4.00
Jones Bob Cray         2           3.80
Mitten Jose Crush         3           1.53
```

How can I get it to all line up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add an int to the name format statement it will align the text:

```
 System.out.printf("%20s", fullName[j]);
```

will print

```
Hoffman Caleb Joseph         1           4.00
      Jones Bob Cray         2           3.80
   Mitten Jose Crush         3           1.53
```

If you want to left justify it then put a minus in front

```
 System.out.printf("%-20s", fullName[j]);
```

will print

```
Hoffman Caleb Joseph         1           4.00
Jones Bob Cray               2           3.80
Mitten Jose Crush            3           1.53
```

As an aside, you don't need 3 separate format statements, you can combine all 3 into 1:

```
System.out.printf("%-20s%10d%15.2f%n", fullName[j], id[j], gpa[j]);
```

Also note the new line is `%n` not `\n`.  `%n` is a format string that will print system dependent new line character(s)

Answer (score 1):

In your format specifiers you should use  a `-` like `"%-10d` to align the columns.